# Почему возникает ошибка Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() в данном случае?

Tags: php, форма, foreach

Страница task_form.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>Интерфейс формы</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="formfortask" action="ask_names.php" method="post">
<h3>Создать элемент "строка ввода текста":</h3>
<input type="checkbox" name="types[]" value="string"><br>
<h3>Количество элементов:</h3>
<input type="text" name="numbers[string]" size="3"><br><br>
<h3>Создать элемент "текстовая область":</h3>
<input type="checkbox" name="types[]" value="text"><br>
<h3>Количество элементов:</h3>
<input type="text" name="numbers[text]" size="3"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Создать">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Страница ask_names.php. Запрос имен элементов формы:

```
<?php 
echo "<meta charset='utf-8'>"; 
// Этот скрипт запрашивает названия элементов формы, которая здесь - task_form.html  
$file = "task.php"; // файл, который будет обрабатывать сгенерированную этим скриптом форму 
function Ask_names() {
    global $file; 
    if (isset($_POST["types"])) {
        $st = '<form action="'.$file.'" method="post">'; 
        foreach ($_POST["types"] as $k => $type) {
            $num = $_POST["numbers"][$type]; 
            for ($i=1; $i<=$num; $i++) {
                $st .= "Введите имя $i-го элемента типа $type: "; 
                $st .= "<input type='text' name=names[$type][]><br>"; 
            }
             $st.= "<input type='hidden' name='types[]' value='$type'>";
             $st.= "<input type='hidden' name='numbers[]' value='$num'><br>";
        }
        $st .= "<input type='submit' name='send' value='Send'></form>";
        return $st; 
    }
    else {
        echo "Select type";
    }
}
echo Ask_names(); 
?>
```

Страница task.php. Создание элементов формы:

```
<?php
echo "<meta charset='utf-8'>"; 
$show_file = "task_show1.php"; 
function Create_element($type, $name) {
    $str = ""; 
    switch ($type) {
        case "string": 
         $str .= "$name: <input type='text' name='string[]'><br>"; 
         break;
        case "text":
         $str .= "$name: <textarea name='text[]'></textarea><br>"; 
         break;
    }
    return $str; 
}
function Create_form() {
    global $show_file; 
    $str = '<form action="'.$show_file.'" method="post">'; 
    foreach ($_POST["types"] as $k => $type) {
        $num = $_POST["numbers"][$k]; 
        for ($i=1; $i<=$num; $i++) {
            $arr = $_POST["names"][$type][$i-1]; 
            $str .= Create_element($type, $arr); 
        }
    }
    $str .= "<input type='submit' value='Send'></form>"; 
    echo $str;
}
$crt = "Create_form"; 
$crt(); 
echo "<hr>";
?>
```

Страница task_show1.php. Обработка формы, которая сгенерирована здесь - task.php:

```
<?php
echo "<meta charset='utf-8'>";
function Create_output() {
    if (isset($_POST["types"])) {
        $st = $_POST["types"];
      foreach ($st as $k => $type) {
        $num = $_POST["numbers"][$k];
        for ($i=1; $i<=$num; $i++) {
            $arr = $_POST["names"][$type][$i-1];
            $arr .= "<br>";
            if ($type == "string") {
                $num1 = $_POST["numbers"][string];
                for ($ii=1; $ii<=$num1; $ii++) {
                    $str = $_POST["string"][$ii-1];
                }
            }
            if ($type == "text") {
                $num1 = $_POST["numbers"][text];
                for ($ii=1; $ii<=$num1; $ii++) {
                    $str = $_POST["text"][$ii-1];
                }
            }
        }
    echo "$arr<br>";
    echo "$str";
    }
}
}
$cro = "Create_output";
$cro();
?>
```

Проблема в том, что обработка формы не проходит, потому что появляется ошибка `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` в 4 строке страницы task_show1.php. Даже с помощью `isset` не проходит обработка, почему-то массив пустой становится. В чем может быть проблема? Как исправить ее?

Comment: task.php не создает ни одного элемента формы с именем types. Так что не удивительно, что в task_show1.php приходит пустой массив.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил свои ошибки, теперь форма на task_show.php проходит обработку корректно. Выкладываю рабочий скрипт каждой страницы.

Страница task_form.html не претерпела изменений. 
Страница ask_names.php:

```
<?php 
echo "<meta charset='utf-8'>";
$file = "task.php";
function Ask_names() {
global $file; 
    if (isset($_POST["types"])) {
        $st = '<form action="'.$file.'" method="post">'; 
        foreach ($_POST["types"] as $k => $type) {
            $num = $_POST["numbers"][$type]; 
            for ($i=1; $i<=$num; $i++) {
                $st .= "Введите имя $i-го элемента типа $type: "; 
                $st .= "<input type='text' name='names[$type][]'><br>"; 
            }
             $st.= "<input type='hidden' name='types[]' value='$type'>";
             $st.= "<input type='hidden' name='numbers[]' value='$num'><br>";
             $st .= "<input type='hidden' name='numbers[$type]' value='$num'>";
        }
        $st .= "<input type='submit' name='send' value='Send'></form>";
        return $st; 
    }
    else {
        echo "Select type";
    }
}
echo Ask_names(); 
?>
```

Страница task.php:

```
<?php
echo "<meta charset='utf-8'>";
$show_file = "task_show2.php"; // этот файл для обработки данных, созданных этим файлом формы 
function Create_element($type, $name) {
    // функция создает элемент ввода по типу и названию 
    $str = ""; 
    switch ($type) {
        case "string": 
         $str .= "$name: <input type='text' name='string[]'><br>"; 
         break;
        case "text":
         $str .= "$name: <textarea name='text[]'></textarea><br>"; 
         break;
    }
    return $str; 
}
function Create_form() {
    // функция создает форму с нужными элементами 
    global $show_file; 
    $str = '<form action="'.$show_file.'" method="post">';
    foreach ($_POST["types"] as $k => $type) {
        $num1 = $_POST["numbers"][$type];
        $num = $_POST["numbers"][$k]; 
        for ($i=1; $i<=$num; $i++) {
            $arr = $_POST["names"][$type][$i-1]; 
            $str .= "<input type='hidden' name='names[$type][]' value='$arr'>";
            $str .= "<input type='hidden' name='numbers[$type]' value='$num1'>";
            $str .= Create_element($type, $arr); 
        }
        $str .= "<input type='hidden' name='numbers[]' value='$num'>";
        $str .= "<input type='hidden' name='types[]' value='$type'>";
    }
    $str .= "<input type='submit' value='Send'></form>"; 
    echo $str;
}

$crt = "Create_form"; 
$crt(); 
foreach ($_POST["types"] as $k1 => $type1) {
    echo "$k1 - $type1 <br>";
}
echo "<hr>";
foreach ($_POST["types"] as $k => $type) {
    $num = $_POST["numbers"][$k];
    for ($i=1; $i<=$num; $i++) {
        $srr = $_POST["names"][$type][$i-1];
        echo "$srr: <br> ";
    }
}
?>
```

Страница task_show2.php:

```
<?php
echo "<meta charset='utf-8'>";
function Output($type, $name, $s) {
    $str = "";
    switch ($type) {
        case "string":
        $str .= "$name:<br>";
        $str .= $_POST["string"][$s-1];
        $str .= "<br>";
        break;
        case "text":
        $str .= "$name:<br>";
        $str .= $_POST["text"][$s-1];
        $str .= "<br>";
        break;
    }
    return $str;
}

function Create_output() {
    if (isset($_POST["types"]) && !empty($_POST["types"])) {
        $str = "";
        foreach ($_POST["types"] as $k => $type) {
            $num = $_POST["numbers"][$type];
            for ($i=1; $i<=$num; $i++) {
                $arr = $_POST["names"][$type][$i-1];
                $str .= Output($type, $arr, $i);
            }
        }   
}
    echo $str; 
}       
$cr_o = "Create_output";
$cr_o();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Делайте проверку на пустоту а не просто существование массива POST.

```
function Create_output() {
if (isset($_POST["types"]) && !empty($_POST["types"])) {
    var_dump($_POST["types"]);exit; // проверьте а всякий случай что в средине
    $st = $_POST["types"];
  foreach ($st as $k => $type) {....
```